# How to get users having birthday today in loopback?

Tags: javascript, node.js, loopbackjs, loopback

I need to send birthday wishes to users in my application.

I have a table "userdetails" with the column "dob". I need a query to retrieve users having a date of birth matching today's date.

For example, if a user has a "dob" value "1991-01-21 00:00:00", I have to send a birthday email to the user.

```
const users = await userdetails.find({
 where: {
   dob: "  " // not sure what goes in there
 },
});
```

Here, I am not sure what I can put in the where field to match my query.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [`[<>]`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Answer (score 1):

If column type is `date`, the code will probably be like this:

```
where: {
    dob: new Date().toISOString().slice(0,10), // '2022-01-25'
},
```